# Cannot call controller from ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have a Rails 4.0 application.  I am having trouble calling my controller from within ActiveAdmin.  The result is I keep getting redirected to my application's home page.  Is there something that ActiveAdmin does to do this redirect?  I thought I could just define the route and have my button use that route to perform my action.

Here is my ActiveAdmin object.  You can see the button to invoke a services controller.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

```rb
ActiveAdmin.register Sale do
  actions :index, :show
  config.sort_order = "order_number_desc"
  STATUS = %w(created completed validated)

  controller do
    def scoped_collection
      Sale.all_completed
    end    
  end

  action_item only: :index do
    link_to "Import Etsy Orders", etsy_path
  end

  index do
    column :order_number
    column "Name" do |sale|
      sale.customer.full_name if sale.customer.presence
    end
    column :total_amount, :sortable => :total_amount do |sale|
      number_to_currency sale.total_amount
    end
    column :status
    column :authorization
    column :updated_at
    column :type_payment
    default_actions
  end

  show do |sale|
    columns do
      column do
        panel "Billing Information" do
          unless sale.customer.nil?
            customer = sale.customer
            h5 "Name: #{ customer.try(:billing_firstname) }"
            h5 "Lastname: #{ customer.try(:billing_lastname) }"
            h5 "Address 1: #{ customer.try(:billing_address1) }"
            h5 "Address 2: #{ customer.try(:billing_address2) }"
            h5 "City: #{ customer.try(:billing_city) }"
            h5 "Country: #{ customer.try(:billing_country) }"
            h5 "Zip: #{ customer.try(:billing_zip).to_s }"
            h5 "State: #{ customer.try(:billing_state) }"
            h5 "Phone: #{ customer.try(:billing_phone) }"
            h5 "Email: #{ customer.try(:billing_email) }"
          end
        end
      end

      column do
        panel "Shipping Information" do
          unless sale.customer.nil?
            customer = sale.customer
            h5 "Name: #{ customer.shipping_firstname }"
            h5 "Lastname: #{ customer.shipping_lastname }"
            h5 "Address 1: #{ customer.shipping_address1 }"
            h5 "Address 2: #{ customer.shipping_address2 }"
            h5 "City: #{ customer.shipping_city }"
            h5 "Country: #{ customer.shipping_country }"
            h5 "Zip: #{ customer.shipping_zip.to_s }"
            h5 "State: #{ customer.shipping_state }"
          end
        end
      end
    end

    attributes_table do
      row :order_number
      row :authorization
      row :shipping
      row :voucher
      row :total_amount
      row :customer
      row :status
      row :type_payment

      panel "Products" do
        table_for sale.sale_items do |t|
          t.column("Product Name") { |item| item.product_feature.product.name }
          t.column("style") { |item| item.product_feature.style }
          t.column("color") { |item| item.product_feature.color }
          t.column("size") { |item| Size.find(item.size_id) }
          t.column("quantity") { |item| item.quantity }
          t.column("extra") { |item| Size.find(item.size_id).extra }
          t.column("price") { |item| item.product_feature.price }
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you tell me what is "services controller" you mentioned?

Comment: Sure, services_controller looks like this:

class ServicesController < ApplicationController
  def etsy
    binding.pry
    response = HttParty.get('<api key>')
  end
end

routes.rb looks like this:

match '/services/etsy', to: 'services#etsy', via: :get, as: "etsy"

I'm thinking I'm doing something wrong from the routes.rb.  Thoughts?

Or do you think this could be a devise thing?

Comment: I see. Actually I don't see a problem at a glance. However, I would do it by adding a `collection action` described here: http://activeadmin.info/docs/8-custom-actions.html#collection-actions rather than using a controller outside ActiveAdmin for a number of reason.